# Shouldn't edit suggestions show up in the inbox and not the notifications area?

Tags: support, notifications, global-inbox

Man, that notifications area, whenever there's something there, I'm jumping with glee. I've got a badge, whoop (okay, maybe a little excessive rejoice, but hey).

Now, today I got a notification, but sadly, it was just an edit suggestion :(. **Should it really be there?** Items of a similar ilk are usually shown in the inbox are they not?

If it's going to stay, at least give it a badge? Maybe a **Someone fixed your crap because you talk nonsense, approve it through gritted teeth** badge :).

Comment: Sure it should be there. It's a notification, not a comment reply. It's not a human sending you a message, it's the system notifying you something happened that you maybe want to know about.

Comment: @MartijnPieters But it's a response to something you did in a question, is it not? It is far more similar to that of items in the Inbox than it is to items in the notification area (they're just badges?)

Comment: It's not called the 'badges' box. It's the notifications box. A suggested edit on your post is a courtesy notification from the system. Note that for certain common bronze badges, the system does *not* notify you anymore when you are deemed 'experienced' (multiple accounts with a minimum rep amount) either, because that would be notifying you too much.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Hmm, so why doesn't a person answering your question appear in the notifications box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inbox is for direct answers to your comments or your questions, plus Careers 2.0 messages. It's for messages *from humans*.

The notifications box is for messages from the *system*. In that box you get messages if you gained a badge, but also if you gained a privilege, if a post of yours was migrated to another site and, as you discovered, a notification that one your posts has been edited or that a suggested edit has been made (inviting you to review the suggested edit).

You seem to be under the misunderstanding the notifications box is only for badges; the box contains far more than just badge-earned messages.

You can access inbox messages in your [global inbox](https://stackexchange.com/users/1031342/mattytommo?tab=inbox) at any time, but the notifications are aggregated from different places and cannot be found in one place once scrolled from view. Notifications are meant to be transient.